# Crosscompiling for ARM926EJ-s device with hardware float operations support

Tags: embedded, arm, cross-compilation

I need to cross compile c++ code for an embedded device with the specs shown below with hardware float operations support. Cross compiling from Ubuntu 20.04 without hardware float support is easy, i can just run `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -marm -mcpu=arm926ej-s  -mfloat-abi=soft -mfpu=vfp` and it will work. When running with `-mfloat-abi=hard` I get:

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: error: ArmSimulateStartStop uses VFP register arguments, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/crtbegin.o does not
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/crtbegin.o
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: error: ArmSimulateStartStop uses VFP register arguments, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/crtend.o does not
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/crtend.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:12: CrossCompile] Error 1
```

I know this processor supports hardware float support, it says in [the arm documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0287b/i1019986.html). I downloaded [buildroot](https://buildroot.uclibc.org/) and [crosstool](http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/) but I don't know how to configure them right for my device hardware. How can I cross compile with VFP support?

**Device specs:**

```
~ $ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
Processor       : ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l) 
BogoMIPS        : 197.83 
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult edsp java 
CPU implementer : 0x41 
CPU architecture: 5TEJ 
CPU variant     : 0x0 
CPU part        : 0x926 
CPU revision    : 5

~ $ cat /proc/version 
Linux version 2.6.36 (owzafs@PCOWZAFS) (gcc version 4.4.1 (Sourcery G++ Lite 2010q1-202) ) #464 PREEMPT Thu Apr 19 13:50:56 CEST 2018
```

**Edit**:
According to [GCC doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/ARM-Options.html):
Using -mfloat-abi=hard with VFP coprocessors is not supported. Use -mfloat-abi=softfp with the appropriate -mfpu option to allow the compiler to generate code that makes use of the hardware floating-point capabilities for these CPUs.

I used `mfloat-abi=softfp` and the code compiles, however, when running the binary on the device, I get `Illegal instruction` (and nothing else).

Comment: Device might not have vfp after all. It should show vfp in cpuinfo features: https://www.cnx-software.com/2018/02/14/human-readable-decoding-of-proc-cpuinfo-for-arm-processors/amp/ .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the objects `crtbegin.o` and `crtend.o` do not match with the main line build.

I feel that the best method is to recompile `crtbegin.s` and `crtend.s` needs to be recompiled with the same setting `-mfloat-abi=hard`, create the seperate `crtbegin.o` and `crtend.o` and retry.